# Get if product created by QuickCreate of Configurable in Observer

Tags: configurable-product, create

Have an environment in which I can only shoot a certain method if the product is simple or configurable (when it is a simple put the son of a configurable I can not shoot), the problem that when I the one Quick Create it triggers as simple, is there any way to differentiate the product was created by the Quick Create or not?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "official ways" (read as attributes) in the code which says that Magento creates simple product via Quick Create function. You may want to observer to the `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` controller when `quickCreateAction()` method is triggered. By doing this, you will identify and set custom special flag (session, cookie etc) for further logic.

In order to assign observer class to listen an event there is `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()` method. The method triggers event as the following:

```
        Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName(),
        array('controller_action' => $this));
```

In the `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <global>
         <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_quickcreate>
                <observers>
                    <captcha>
                        <class>custom_module/observer</class>
                        <method>setQuickCreateFlag</method>
                    </captcha>
                </observers>
             </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_quickcreate>
         </event>
    </global>
</config>
```

In the `Custom_Module_Model_Observer::setQuickCreateFlag()` method insert your logic.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem to realize what you said, is that I have to change the Core or overwrite it, a simpler way to do this would be useful.

Comment: You should not touch any lines of Core code. It is about adding your customisation on top of Core code with legal ways such as event/observer mechanism.